# Changing svg dimensions with styled component mediaquery does not update viewBox

Tags: svg, media-queries, styled-components

**Example**

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { ReactComponent as SvgLogoUnstyled } from 'src/assets/svg/logo.svg';
const SvgLogo = styled(SvgLogoUnstyled)`
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;

  @media (max-width:1427px){
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
  }
`;
export default SvgLogo;
```

When changing screen size, the svg viewBox remains at 40px, but gets cropped at 17px.
In html css this does not happen. Both the viewBox and dimensions get updated.

Can anyone advise a fix?

Note: Using transform scale - does not resolve this problem, because it keeps the width at 40px which adds unnecessary margin, when I do actually need the logo to be at 17px width.

```css
 transform: scale(0.42); /*17 / .4*/
```

I have managed to hack it a little but its ugly

```
  @media (max-width:1427px){
    transform: scale(0.42);    /* transform: scale(0.42); /*17 / .4*/
    margin: 0 -12px 0 4px;     /* added minus margin to reset ( (40 - 17) / 2)*/
    box-sizing: content-box;   /*  enable expansion without cropping if additional margin top/bottom*/
  }
```

Comment: What is the SVG (in the browser)??.. the React notation is only the recipe to create SVG output.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I can't share it as its a branded logo. This problem exists whatever the type of svg.

Comment: Then show the SVG React creates with a dummy logo. If you say **a 40px** _**viewBox**_ i suspect your error is there somehow, because the SVG viewBox does **not** take units

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman The viewBox is viewBox="0 0 40 40". It has no unit type

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turned out to be simple.
I was using css to set the width and height and change it on mediaquery, but the actual svg itself had a width,height on it. Simply removing the width, height from the svg, but keeping the viewBox, ensured the svg retained its aspect ratio.
Answer here: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Point going forward, when creating svgs, remove the width, height attributes from them before inserting into html and always use css to set the dimensions.

Comment: Next time post the SVG, there are at least 5 people who had commented to remove the attributes, within 15 minutes

Comment: I could not share the svg as mentioned due to brand. Yes I could have mocked up example. Still accuracy matters, and actually there were only 2 people who replied none who said 'remove attributes'.

Comment: Because for those 2 its so obvious you don't set dimensions on the SVG node; and we stopped asking the obvious question years ago. No worries.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman We are always learning new things, and thus forgetting some old things. Nevertheless, as developers we don't know everything. As advanced as the mensa IQ rocket scientist, they may lack the basics to toast bread.