Keeping aspect ratio of internal SVG
I have a root SVG element, defined as this (inserted at the top of the <body>):
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="svg-library">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="image1" viewBox="-10 0 828 1000">
            <path fill="currentColor"
                d="…" />
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>

Now, I “instantiate” the image from the library:
<svg class="inline"> <!-- .inline { fill: currentColor; display: inline-block; } -->
    <use href="#image1"></use>
</svg>

I want it to be 1em height and keep aspect ratio (828 ÷ 1000, see viewBox). What CSS or attributes do I use?
Setting height: 1em; width: auto; makes it 1em height, but width seems to be 100% of a container.
Setting aspect-ratio: auto; doesn't help either, I guess, the ratio defined by the viewBox isn't intrinsic.

Have you tried giving the use element a viewBox attribute?

Don't apply width and height to svg. Just use css to change 1 of those parameters - width or height, not both. Another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387929/changing-svg-dimensions-with-styled-component-mediaquery-does-not-update-viewbox/66396574#66396574

Hello @RobertLongson, I want the viewBox to be defined just once for sake of DRY.

But you also want it to work, no? Which do you want more?

Hello @Inspiraller, if I set just CSS height property, the result is the same as setting width to auto.

Note that using  to avoid multiple copies i.e. DRY is usually a terrible idea. Performance of  is miserable because its purpose is to keep the contents of multiple instances in sync when they change.

@RobertLongson No, I don't work the code to “just work”. I want it to be correct. I could just calculate width value myself and set it to 3.312rem. But the next time the image1 changes, the whole layout is broken.

Then you may need to use javascript to get the viewBox attribute value from the symbol and copy it to the use element. Or just make a comment in the markup to update it manually.

@RobertLongson I'd like to avoid using JS if possible. The point on performance is valuable, thank you, but right now I prefer normalization over speed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Is the preserveAspectRatio attribute what you are looking for? It determines how the svg should behave when it gets different sizes and aspect ratios. It's a bit of a complex attribute with loads of values but I think it should help with what you are doing.

Hello @somethinghere, I've tried setting preserveAspectRatio to the <svg> containing <use>, but it doesn't affect the ratio. As far as I understood, preserveAspectRatio works only if you set a different viewBox.

You need to set a viewBox for the SVG containing your use instance.  This parent  won't adapt to the symbol's viewBox. See also "How to preserve aspect ratio of a SVG symbol?"

You can use the CSS property aspect-ratio.


p {
  color: navy;
}

.inline {
  fill: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  aspect-ratio: 828/1000;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute;">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="image1" viewBox="-10 0 828 1000">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M -10 50 L 818 0 L 690 1000 L 40 700 Z" />
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
<p>Here is your inline <svg class="inline"><use href="#image1" /></svg> SVG.</p>




Thank you. Unfortunately this requires aspect ratio synchronization between the source (viewBox) and CSS.
